# Is there a way to prevent ios frame rate from starting low

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I am working on a swift app and am using AVFoundation to capture video input. When I run the app there is about a 1 second period at the start where the FPS is 30, but then it goes to 60 and maintains that consistently. I have my async call below. I am trying to wait for the FPS to hit 60 before displaying what I want to show.

```
sessionQueue.async {
    \\... other code here ...
    self.session.startRunning()
    self.isSessionRunning = self.session.isRunning

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        rootLayer = self.jetView.layer
        self.jetView.frame = rootLayer.bounds
        setup(videoInput: self.videoDeviceInput, view: self)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your framerate is mostly determined by the amount of work you are doing on the main thread, which is impacted by the amount of rendering changes and the work it takes to render.

You should profile and try to reduce this as much as possible.  Perhaps with a simpler presentation animation or perhaps you should consider a simple manual layout if you have a complex auto-layout.  (those are typical VC start framerate issues)

You need to profile to be sure.

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/4784723-instruments-tutorial-getting-started